# Enable/Set TLS1.2 as default in Win 2008 R2

Tags: ssl

Vendor said that they are going to end support of TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 for an API interface that we are using via an vendor bundled software code that is written in .NET.  I assume the application is using its windows component to establish the connection with the vendor api. Any suggestion how to enable the TLS1.2 on this Windows 2008 R2 server where we have the application installed?
I tried the steps mentioned in this link(https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a433/how-to-enable-tls-1_2-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx ) it doesn’t seems to work as we expected. Is there a way to check if the TLS1.2 is properly enable (or) set TLS1.2 as default on this server?

Comment: People often use [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chandra

I think you are looking at this problem the wrong way. Your vendor is improving their security position by disabling the weaker protocols TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on their services. You shouldn’t need to configure your servers to disable the same protocols.

What you need to do is get an updated version of the vendors bundled software that has been written/configured to use the TLS 1.2 protocol or rewrite the parts of the application that makes the api calls to use the latest protocol.

Now depending on which version of .Net you are running will determine how it’s done. Anything under .Net 3.5.1 SP 1 will not work. .Net 3.5.1 does support it but does not have the appropriate constant so it requires the appropriate value to be passed as the correct type. With .Net 4 and above it should be a simple process of passing a parameter to use TLS 1.2 directly.

You should be able to google for examples on how to set the parameter fo a given version of .Net